# Websocket returns null values

Tags: karate

When i am trying execute the below code

Scenario: demo

```
* def socket = karate.webSocket("wss://socketsbay.com/wss/v2/1/demo/")
* socket.send('Test Karate')
  And listen 5000
  Then match listenResult == 'Test Karate'
```

i am getting below error

22:02:32.320 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG c.i.k.http.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket client connected

22:02:32.330 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - entered listen state with timeout: 5000

22:02:37.335 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - listen timed out: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

22:02:37.336 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - exit listen state with result: null

22:02:37.348 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:websocket/test.feature:28

Then match listenResult == 'Test Karate'
match failed: EQUALS
$ | data types don't match (NULL:STRING)
null
'Test Karate'

Meanwhile in socketsbay.com ui i can able to notice message has been delivered and i can able to see below screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNZwQ.png)

Requesting to help here

Comment: Sorry for the unorganized format above this is the first time i am posting question in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Because you have to send a message from the server.

```
* def socket = karate.webSocket('wss://socketsbay.com/wss/v2/1/demo/')
* listen 10000
* match listenResult == 'test'
```

After starting the test, I went to the UI, clicked "Connect" and then typed `test` and clicked "Send". It worked fine:

```
22:34:34.521 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1]  DEBUG c.i.k.http.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket client connected
22:34:34.552 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate - entered listen state with timeout: 10000
22:34:41.549 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate - exit listen state with result: test
22:34:41.771 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1]  DEBUG c.i.k.http.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket closing
22:34:41.786 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1]  DEBUG c.i.k.http.WebSocketClientHandler - websocket client disconnected
```